# Using my.settings system.drawing.size and textbox.text

Tags: vb.net, my.settings

Problem:

I want to change the size of the panel and save it so the next time I open the program it will keep the size of the panel. Because of this I manage to use `my.settings` with type of `system.drawing.size`

However I am having a problem on converting it, so I can initially output the default size of my `my.settings`

```
My.Settings.pnl_service_size = Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text
```

> Error 1   Value of type 'System.Drawing.Size' cannot be converted to 'String'.

I am aware on how to use my.settings, I am just having a hard time on converting this so i can output it to my textbox.text.

**Edit:**

How I populate the textbox is in `OnLoad event`

```
Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text = My.Settings.pnl_service_size.ToString 'I populate the textbox
Pnl_Service.Size = New Size(My.Settings.pnl_service_size) 'The panel that I want to change the size
```

How I save the textbox is by pressing the `OnClicked button`

```
My.Settings.pnl_service_size = Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text.ToString
My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: Its wanting a string, not a size. So give it what it wants... Also your code shows assigning a string to a Size, where do you assign the Size to the string?

Comment: @JeremyThompson ah yes. I am assigning the size on form load using this code `Pnl_Service.Size = New Size(My.Settings.pnl_service_size)` and yes I also have `Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text = My.Settings.pnl_service_size`

Comment: Just put a **ToString()** eg, ....Text =My.Settings.pnl_service_size.ToString()

Comment: I also tried converting it to string like this `CStr(My.Settings.pnl_service_size) = Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text`. I don't understand.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you so much. It works, but I am having a problem on `Cstr(My.Settings.pnl_service_size) = Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text` I also tried `My.Settings.pnl_service_size.tostring = Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text`

Comment: You only cast (eg cstr) variables you're assigning - in your comment you cstr the value your assigning to - that's wrong. Please provide the full code including the line the error occurs on

Comment: Done Sir, thank you so much for your assistance. I would love to learn why it doesn't work and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

A key piece of info is what type the variable is for the value in `My.Settings`.

```
My.Settings.pnl_service_size = Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text.ToString
```

This makes it look like it is string.  The problem is that this will save something like:  `{Width=237, Height=133}` which will easily not convert back to a `Size` variable.

If the Type used in `Settings`, is `System.Drawing.Size` then you do not need to convert to string to save it:

```
My.Settings.pnl_service_size = Pnl_Service.Size
```

Reset the size next time:

```
Pnl_Service.Size = My.Settings.pnl_service_size
```

You can show the value using `.ToString()` but since the result is `String`, it cannot by used as a `Size`.

```
TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.pnl_service_size.ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I set a new size on `my.settings.pnl_service_size`? This code is my problem `My.Settings.pnl_service_size = Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text`. Yes, I declared the settings as `system.drawing.size`.

Comment: `Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text` is a string, it is not a size. The first sentence in your question is about saving and restoring the size of a panel. So save it from the Panel as I show.  Passing the size thru a Textbox changes it to a string so you get the error you.  You can show it in a TB but you cannot use it as a size from there.  Maybe you could explain why the Panel.Size needs to come from a TextBox

Comment: Thanks! Because of you I realized that I'm doing it the hard way, please see my answer. I now used the `string` as type of my `my.settings` instead of `system.drawing.size`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to use the textbox to indicate the size of certain object.

I changed the type of `my.settings` from `system.drawing.size` to `string` the this is how i used it.

Populating the textbox during `OnLoad event`

```
'I populate the textbox
Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text = My.Settings.pnl_service_size 

'The panel that I want to change the size
Dim pnl_size As Array = Split(My.Settings.pnl_service_size, ",", 2)
Pnl_Service.Size = New Size(pnl_size(0), pnl_size(1))
```

Saving the `textbox` to `my.settings` by pressing the `OnClicked button`

```
My.Settings.pnl_service_size = Tb_Pnl_Service_Size.Text
My.Settings.Save()
```